# Loading custom jQuery and HTML in a WordPress page

Tags: pages, templates, html

I have a simple application I have worked on and would like to load it into my WordPress theme.

This app has a `/js` folder with `myscript.js`, a `/css` folder with `mystyle.css` and an HTML file `index.html`.

Here is the [fiddle to the whole app](http://jsfiddle.net/tKKY6/5/).

I am using the default WordPress theme and all I want to do is create a page for this app and load it there. This way I can create another page and load another app.

Efforts made:
From what I have read I need to enqueue my custom JS script which I have done like this and added to `functions.php` file:

```
/**
 * A small function to load my custom JScript file for WordCount
 */
function my_script() {
    if ( is_page(23) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'my-script',
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my-script.js',
            array('jquery')
        );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_script', 1 );
```

My only challenge is: where would my `index.html` code go to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this in a [page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates).

In your theme, create a file named `page-app.php` with the following content:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: App
 */

function wpdev_137109_enqueue_scripts() {
    $file = '/js/myscript.js';
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'myscript',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . $file,
        array( 'jquery' ),
        filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . $file ),
        TRUE
    );

    $file = '/css/mystyle.css';
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'mystyle',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . $file,
        array(),
        filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . $file )
    );
} // function wpdev_137109_enqueue_scripts
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdev_137109_enqueue_scripts' );
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="sys-mbox">
    <textarea id="sys-tbox"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="sys-results">
    Total number of words: <span class="words"> </span>
    Total number of chars: <span class="character"> </span>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Put your stylesheet and script files in the mentioned locations.

Then create a WordPress page and select the page template *App* from the *Page Attributes* meta box. Hit save and you're done.

**// EDIT:**
As for jQuery, try it like so:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // code...
});
```

Comment: Great let me try this but does it matter which Theme I have activated?

Comment: This file will need to be in the active theme

Comment: Sure its an Active Theme. I am running into slight issue as it appears WordPress does not like my $ in the JS script. I read I need to change $ to jQuery. I have done it but it appears it does not like anything $ to be declared

Comment: sorry but I already done that. Stuck with error **TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function**. Its failing at **var text = $(field).val();** It appears it does not like $

Comment: Please ignore me. All I had to do was change wherever $ to jQuery and it worked :)

Comment: You are a genius. Thanks for your help. The best I have seen so far